# accidentally I did remove these files (lesspipe and sh) how can re-back them again?

Tags: command-line

I was trying to remove some files and directories on my system but I didn't know so, I read about (wipe) command so, I thought that I may delete the files by it but I stopped the command running and when I tried open terminal again I did find this message at the beginning of CMD:

```
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

so, please if anyone can help me anything instead of reboot or set up my system again I will be so appreciable.

Comment: We have no details of what OS/release you are talking about, if it's a desktop, server, a text terminal, virtual terminal etc. Providing your exact commands you used and exact output (my own system has no `wipe` command installed for example)

Answer (score 0):

To get `lesspipe` back you have to reinstall [its package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Flesspipe):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall less
```